# Почему response body пустой?

Tags: c#, api, swagger, response, body

Написал аутентификацию, которая возвращает все данные пользователя, если login и password введены верно. Тут всё хорошо.
Код файла DataBaseManager:

```
public static User AuthUser(User user)
    {
        if (sqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlConnection.Open();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                $"SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE login = @login AND password = @password",
                sqlConnection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("login", user.login);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", user.password);

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                user.id = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0));
                user.lastName = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(1));
                user.firstName = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(2));
                user.patronymic = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(3));
                user.phoneNumber = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(4));
                user.address = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(5));
                user.role = (Role)Convert.ToInt16(reader.GetValue(8));
            }
                sqlConnection.Close();
                return user;
        }
        catch
        {
            sqlConnection.Close();
            return user;
        }
    }
```

Код файла UserController:

```
[HttpPost("~/Authentication")]
    public User Authentication(string login, string password)
    {
        return DataBaseManager.AuthUser(
            new User(login, password));
    }
```

Возвращает он:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее я хочу получать всю информацию о транспортной компании, но параметры мне передавать, по сути, не имеет смысла.
Код файла DataBaseManager:

```
public static SDEK GetInfoSDEK(SDEK sdek)
    {
        if (sqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlConnection.Open();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                $"SELECT * FROM [TransportCompanies] WHERE name = @name",
                sqlConnection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", sdek.name);

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                sdek.id = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0));
                sdek.price_km = Convert.ToDecimal(reader.GetValue(2));
                sdek.price_kg = Convert.ToDecimal(reader.GetValue(3));
                sdek.price_insurance = Convert.ToDecimal(reader.GetValue(4));
            }
            sqlConnection.Close();
            return sdek;
        }
        catch
        {
            sqlConnection.Close();
            return sdek;
        }
    }
```

Код файла TransportCompanyController:

```
[HttpGet("~/GetInfoSDEK")]
    public SDEK GetInfoSDEK()
    {
        return DataBaseManager.GetInfoSDEK(new SDEK());
    }
```

Возвращает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне требуется, чтобы он вернул экземпляр класса SDEK, но он этого не делает.
Проверял через отладку - все данные записывает и видит.
Класс SDEK подключен как библиотека (по заданию).

Вопрос: Что я делаю не так?

UPDATE: "Покажите модели данных User и SDEK"

Модель User:

```
    namespace DeliveryApp
{
    public enum Role
    {
        User,
        Admin
    }
    public class User
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string patronymic { get; set; }
        public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string login { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public Role role { get; set; }


        public User(string lastName, string firstName, string patronymic, string phoneNumber, string address, string login, string password, Role role = Role.User)
        {
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.patronymic = patronymic;
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
            this.address = address;
            this.login = login;
            this.password = password;
            this.role = role;
        }
        public User(string login, string password)
        {
            this.login = login;
            this.password = password;
        }
    }
}
```

Модель SDEK:

```
namespace TransportCompany1
{
    public class SDEK
    {
        public int id = -1;
        public string name = "SDEK";
        public decimal price_km = 0;
        public decimal price_kg = 0;
        public decimal price_insurance = 0;

        public SDEK(int id, string name, decimal price_km, decimal price_kg, decimal price_insurance) // СЕРВЕР: Отвечает клиенту, если такая транспортная компания существует.
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.price_km = price_km;
            this.price_kg = price_kg;
            this.price_insurance = price_insurance;
        }
        public SDEK() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Для тех, кто хранит в базе пароли в открытом виде, есть отдельный котел в аду. :) Используйте хэширование.

Comment: Лучше бы с проблемой помогли :)
Хэширование - прикладная вещь, мне нужен простой ответ от сервера.
Ну.. или хотя бы от человека.

Comment: Покажите модели данных `User` и `SDEK`

Comment: Изменил вопрос.
Повторюсь, модель SDEK находится в библиотеке классов, которую я подключаю.
Каждое изменение SDEK`a я пересобирал два проекта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратите внимание, что в классе `User` у вас свойства

```
public int id { get; set; }
```

А в классе `SDEK` у вас поля

```
public int id = -1;
```

Для того чтобы модель сериализовалась, нужны свойства

```
public int id { get; set; } = -1;
```

Comment: Он всё ещё возвращает {}, хотя данные он видит.

Comment: @Danila обновил ответ

Comment: С полем name в SDEK также поступить?

Comment: @Danila со всеми полями, которые вы хотите сериализовать в JSON. Сериализатор по умолчанию поля пропускает.

Comment: Большое спасибо :)

Comment: @Danila хэширование! SHA256 берите, не прогадаете.

Comment: Обязательно этим займусь! :)